# Fatal Error: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gpu, opengles, make, games

I'm trying to install Urho3D on RPi 3. (GPU = 768 MB)

I installed all the essential dependencies. All the steps went fine.
Until this error which occurred during the final make step:

```
[ 56%] Building CXX object Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/Graphics/Skybox.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/Graphics/Graphics.cpp.o
In file included from /root/Urho3D/Source/Urho3D/Graphics/../Graphics/GraphicsImpl.h:29:0,
                 from /root/Urho3D/Source/Urho3D/Graphics/Graphics.cpp:34:
/root/Urho3D/Source/Urho3D/Graphics/../Graphics/OpenGL/OGLGraphicsImpl.h:36:23: fatal error: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GLES2/gl2.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/build.make:1916: recipe for target 'Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/Graphics/Graphics.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/Graphics/Graphics.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1198: recipe for target 'Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [Source/Urho3D/CMakeFiles/Urho3D.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:137: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any suggestions?
What should I do !?

Answer (score 3):

The file `GLES2/gl2.h` belongs to the package called `libgles2-mesa-dev`, which you should install with `apt-get`.

Comment: I think it is just a missing include path. on Raspbian GLES2 is located in `/opt/vc`. The Raspberry Pi Foundation has it's own implementation that is specific to the Pi while MESA might not take full advantage of the hardware.

Comment: @kwasmich Hey, thanks - I didn't know about this folder's purpose. Which utterly defeats the purpose of POSIX directory naming, btw. *Optional* video drivers? Really?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I doubt those responsible actually care, I think the secret history of linux on the Pi is that it was a bit grudging but too practical to be avoided ;)  Anyway there's a bin directory in there (with stuff like `raspicam` and `vcgencmd`) too, but Raspbian *probably* has that in `$PATH` and there should be an entry for the linker in `/etc/ld.so.conf` -- but I do not have a pi to check right now and the OP does not mention an OS.  Anyway the upstream source is in the firmware repo: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware (the `hardfp` version, probably).

Comment: To split hairs a bit: I wouldn't really call openGL a "video driver" BTW, it's a userspace graphics library stacked on top of appropriate drivers, but the two have some significant coupling.

Comment: So @goldilocks , what do I have to do now? This error occures in Raspbian OS.

Comment: @Omid1989 So there is a linker entry for the `/opt/vc/lib` stuff but that file is not there.  I would just work with the MESA lib for now.  Traditionally on linux it's associated with software emulation of GL hardware, but I am not positive this is necessarily the case currently.  That's something you might check with them and/or the Urho3D devs.

Answer (score 0):

On dec. 29th 2018, with nov. 13th 2018 raspbian stretch full img, this worked:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxrandr-dev libasound2-dev git cmake make libgl1-mesa-dev
mkdir Src
cd Src
git clone https://github.com/urho3d/Urho3D
cd Urho3D
./script/cmake_rpi.sh .
make
```

(the rpi specific script takes care of the very special local video driver
by declaring the RPI symbol)